# Autofac - resolving through factory methods

Tags: c#, autofac, ioc-container, interceptor, factory-method

I just can't seem to wrap my brain around this situation in Autofac:

- My business logic needs an object of type IFinal.
- The implementing class Final has several dependencies that are not known by the business logic, but can be directly resolved via the IoCContainer.
- Final also has other dependencies that are only known by the business logic at run time.
- I want to be able to use Interceptors on IFinal, so class Final should be registered and resolved via IFinal.

So I tried to create a factory for IFinal, but I can't seem to get the resolution right.

Example code:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<Dependency>().As<IDependency>();

        builder.RegisterType<Final>().As<IFinal>();

        // this fails because context c is not available at the time finalObjectFactoryMethod is used
        builder.Register<Factory>((c,p)=>{
            var dependency = c.Resolve<IDependency>();
            Func<int, IFinal> finalObjectFactoryMethod =
                rta => c.Resolve<IFinal>(
                    new TypedParameter(typeof(IDependency), dependency),
                    new TypedParameter(typeof(int), rta)
                );
            return new Factory(finalObjectFactoryMethod);
        }).As<IFactory>();

        // this works but doesn't use the resolve mechanism for IFinal
        /*
        builder.Register<Factory>((c,p)=>{
            var dependency = c.Resolve<IDependency>();
            Func<int, IFinal> finalObjectFactoryMethod = rta => new Final(dependency, rta);
            return new Factory(finalObjectFactoryMethod);
        }).As<IFactory>();
        */

        IContainer container = builder.Build();


        IFactory factory = container.Resolve<IFactory>();
        IFinal final = factory.GetFinalObject(42);
    }
}


public interface IDependency{}

public class Dependency: IDependency{}


public interface IFinal
{
    void Test();
}

public class Final: IFinal
{
    public Final(IDependency dependency, int runtimeArgument){}

    public void Test(){}
}


public interface IFactory
{
    IFinal GetFinalObject(int runtimeArgument);
}

public class Factory: IFactory
{
    readonly Func<int, IFinal> _finalObjectFactoryMethod;

    public Factory(Func<int, IFinal> finalObjectFactoryMethod)
    {
        _finalObjectFactoryMethod = finalObjectFactoryMethod;
    }

    public IFinal GetFinalObject(int runtimeArgument)
    {
        return _finalObjectFactoryMethod(runtimeArgument);
    }
}
```

Google and Autofac documentation could not help me on this.
Somehow there seems to be a knot in my brain, maybe I just try to use the wrong pattern.
I'm pretty sure there is a solution for this, but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 7):

You have to add a *factory* `delegate` to `Final`:

```
public class Final : IFinal
{
    public delegate IFinal Factory(int runtimeArgument);

    public Final(IDependency dependency, int runtimeArgument) { }

    public void Test() { }
}
```

Autofac is clever enough to fill the other parameters in so your factory delegate can only have parameters you specify at runtime and the other ones are resolved by *magic*.

Then you register the type:

```
    builder
        .RegisterType<Final>()
        .As<IFinal>();
```

Here's the complete example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder
        .RegisterType<Dependency>()
        .As<IDependency>();

    builder
        .RegisterType<Final>()
        .As<IFinal>();

    using(var container = builder.Build())
    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {

        var finalFactory = scope.Resolve<Final.Factory>();
        IFinal final = finalFactory(42);
    }
}
```

You don't need the `Factory` class at all. The delegate can either be resolved directly from `scope` or used the same way as any other dependency and injected by Autofac. Just juse `Final.Factory` as your dependency.

The documentation describes this technique in the [Delegate Factories](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html#creation-through-factories)

Comment: I think my only complaint is that this exposes `Final`, an otherwise `internal` implementation detail (in my case), to the outside world. In your example, `Final` is `public` but one may not always want the interface implementations exposed outside of its assembly.

Answer (score 3):

Great example of "ask the right question and you'll find the right answer".
I've been trying to get this to work for 2 days now and 1 hour after I posted my question here, I found the answer myself :P

Here's the working code including Interceptor:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<Interceptor>();

        builder.RegisterType<Dependency>().As<IDependency>();

        builder.RegisterType<Final>().As<IFinal>();

        builder.Register<IFinal>((c, p) =>
        {
            IDependency dependency = c.Resolve<IDependency>();
            int runtimeArgument = p.Named<int>("runtimeArgument");
            return new Final(dependency, runtimeArgument);
        }).As<IFinal>()
       .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
       .InterceptedBy(typeof(Interceptor));

        builder.Register<Factory>((c,p)=>{
            Factory.FactoryMethod finalObjectFactoryMethod = c.Resolve<Factory.FactoryMethod>();
            return new Factory(finalObjectFactoryMethod);
        }).As<IFactory>()
       .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
       .InterceptedBy(typeof(Interceptor));

        IContainer container = builder.Build();


        IFactory factory = container.Resolve<IFactory>();
        IFinal final = factory.GetFinalObject(42);
        final.Test();
    }
}


public interface IDependency{}

public class Dependency: IDependency{}


public interface IFinal
{
    void Test();
}

public class Final: IFinal
{
    public Final(IDependency dependency, int runtimeArgument){}

    public void Test(){}
}


public interface IFactory
{
    IFinal GetFinalObject(int runtimeArgument);
}

public class Factory: IFactory
{
    public delegate IFinal FactoryMethod(int runtimeArgument);

    readonly FactoryMethod _finalObjectFactoryMethod;

    public Factory(FactoryMethod finalObjectFactoryMethod)
    {
        _finalObjectFactoryMethod = finalObjectFactoryMethod;
    }

    public IFinal GetFinalObject(int runtimeArgument)
    {
        return _finalObjectFactoryMethod(runtimeArgument);
    }
}

public class Interceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"call {invocation.Method.Name}");
        invocation.Proceed();
        Console.WriteLine($"return from {invocation.Method.Name}");
    }
}
```

The interceptor now writes this to the console:

```
call GetFinalObject
return from GetFinalObject  
call Test  
return from Test
```

Maybe this can help anyone else.

Comment: Oh, good to know. I've never worked with interceptors before. Nice and I know the feeling, you ask and find the answer yourself a few minutes later ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in the other comments very unsatisfying. That's why I wrapped my head around the example. Perhaps you or others can benefit from it.

Though the example is **syntactically** correct, my hypothesis is that it is incorrect from a **semantical** point of view.

Some explanation:
I prefer to code **compile time dependencies** using constructor injection (like you and others already do). **Runtime dependencies** on the other hand are passed using method arguments.

Therefor I suggest to redesign your classes in such a way that *runtimeArgument* is passed to the *Test()* method. For me it looks like this argument is not needed at an earlier stage.

```
public interface IDependency { }

public class Dependency : IDependency { }

public interface IFinal
{
    void Test(int runtimeArgument);
}

public class Final : IFinal
{
    public Final(IDependency dependency) { }

    public void Test(int runtimeArgument)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Argument is {runtimeArgument}.");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var svc = Service;
        svc.Test(42);
    }

    private static IFinal Service
    {
        get
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<Final>()
                .As<IFinal>();

            builder.RegisterType<Dependency>()
                .As<IDependency>();

            var container = builder.Build();

            using var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();
            {
                return scope.Resolve<IFinal>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, well... It's been some time since then :D
Your solution works if the runtime argument is known where the Test() method is used.
If it's not (like in my case, if I remember right), then it must be attached to the object beforehand. That's why I wanted to initialize it in the constructor.

Comment: If the argument is not known at the place where Test() is called it is at least known somewhere else - and this somewhere else is the dependency which I would pass into the object. This is in contrast of making the argument itself a dependency.